# The Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN)

Tags: sql-server, cdc

When we start CDC capture job `cdc.Job_Capture` then we receive following error:

> Log Scan process failed in processing log records. Refer to previous errors in the current session to identify the cause and correct any associated problems.
>
> Error 18805

Comment: I'll ask the dumb question: are there any previous errors as this error message would suggest there might be?

Comment: Previous Errors were :
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'start_lsn' table [database].cdc.lsn_time_mapping

We referred below link and tried the solution:
https://mrfoxsql.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/new-bug-change-data-capture-cdc-fails-after-alter-column/


SELECT
    [AllocUnitName] as [ObjectName],
    [Page ID],
    [Current LSN],
    [Operation],
    [Context],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Description]
FROM
    fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Current LSN] = '00000030:000001ab:0007'


But [ObjectName] was null for LSN which was giving error.

Comment: Is this a new CDC install or is it an existing one that has become broken? If it was an existing one, did you make any change to the table recently or to the CDC configuration? Is it a possibility to drop the existing change instance and add it back?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to drop existing CDC as we need to maintain historical data. Is there any other way around?

Comment: I'm unsure - I'm not able to find any information on the error that you posted that seem helpful. My question about whether or not any change to the underlying table or the CDC configuration have been made recently hasn't been answered. I find it hard to believe that something that was working would just stop working absent an external catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query below, which will return CDC errors.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_cdc_errors
```

In my case one of system SP `sp_ins_instance_enabling_lsn_time_mapping` got deleted, this one will be created as part of enabling CDC, for some reason this SP got deleted. Not sure what caused this. CDC capture job is passing after i created this SP